# Ignite: work with messaging and less dependencies

Tags: rest, dependencies, messaging, ignite

I'm writing a microservice for an existing Ignite cluster. I need to have basic communications with Ignite Messaging system, and don't need other Ignite capabilities. I don't want to include Ignite libraries as it will bloat my microservice - ignite.zip is about 10 times larger than my server and I only need a small subset of functionality.

How can I send messages to existing Ignite cluster and receive messages from it?

EDIT: Ignite documentation lists REST API as one of ways to use Ignite. I'm not sure how it can be used to work with Ignite messaging - suppose I want to receive message as soon as it becomes available in the Ignite messaging? I don't want to poll for messages, as that's not efficient enough for me. If using REST API, the question becomes: how (if it's possible) to receive message using Ignite REST API from the distributed messaging system?

Comment: Is ignite-core-2.0.0.jar dependency too big for you? It is only 8MB.

Comment: Maybe not too big. I'm researching this now.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need only one JAR - ignite-core, which doesn't have any additional dependencies.

To achieve functionality, you can start a client node in your application and use `IgniteMessaging` API: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/messaging

Comment: After

`Ignition.setClientMode(true);
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
`
I'm getting

`Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl
`
I don't see IgniteSpringHelperImpl in ignite-core-2.0.0.jar . What's wrong?

Comment: You are using the Ignite/Spring integration. Please take a look at ignite-spring-2.0.0.jar

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy. I've created [a separate question for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010153/ignite-using-core-only-to-have-messaging)